# time format conversion unsupported

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, strptime, python-datetime

I need to convert into a datetime object the string `'21h03m'`.

`%d/%m/%Y %Hh%Mm'` does not work, I suspect because of the characters `h` and `m` in the string.

Is there any straightforward way to convert it, or do I need to modify the string and remove/replace `h` and `m`?

Answer (score 0):

Literals like your `h` and `m` characters in the `datetime.strptime()` format string work *just fine*.

Your input has *no date component* however. Remove the `%d/%m/%Y` portion and parsing works (albeit that the result has a standard date of 1900-01-01):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('21h03m', '%Hh%Mm')
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 21, 3)
```